# Does BigQuery Copy datasets feature is using slots?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery Dataset Copy (see more here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) per documentation is mentioning that is using BigQuery Data Transfer Service. But what right now is unclear to me is question if BigQuery Data Transfer Service is using slots or not? I tried to find any information about in documentation but failed. They are used for ingestion jobs, so I was curious if this is also a case for Data Transfer Service.

Comment: Hello. If you found my answer helpful consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, do let me know so that the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [video](https://youtu.be/iyYN733UIN0?t=212) from Google Cloud Tech, `PIPELINE` type jobs (extract, load and **copy jobs**) do take up slots if they are assigned reservations. The [dataset copy documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#:%7E:text=Copying%20a%20dataset%20requires%20one%20copy%20job%20for%20each%20table%20in%20the%20dataset.) states that each table in the intended dataset gets its own copy job and so, it seems that copy jobs do take up slots.

Quoting from the documentation.

> Copying a dataset requires one copy job for each table in the dataset.

If no slots are assigned to `PIPELINE` type jobs, they use the shared pool of free slots by default.

Comment: I've watched the video and my understanding that `PIPELINE` type of job is related to BigQuery table copy (see here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table) but not about BigQuery Data Transfer Service which is copying dataset. Just want to double check if this is also related to BQ Data Transfer Service for copying dataset which is different than BigQuery copy table?

Comment: @galuszkak BigQuery Data Transfer Service uses table copy jobs under the hood to copy a dataset. DTS uses [one copy job per table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#copy_quotas) to copy the entire dataset.